# Print inside a for loop in C#

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, printing

I'm trying to print inside a for loop where a groupbox have to be printed until the condition satisfies.

//Code:

```
private void btnPrint_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            for (int i = 1; i <= Convert.ToInt32(lblTotalBox.Text); i++)
            {
                lblBoxNumber.Text = i.ToString();
                printDocument1.Print();
            }
        }



private void printDocument1_PrintPage(object sender, PrintPageEventArgs e)
        {

            PaperSize paperSize = new PaperSize("MyCustomSize", 100, 65);
            paperSize.RawKind = (int)PaperKind.Custom;
            printDocument1.DefaultPageSettings.PaperSize = paperSize;

            using (Graphics g = e.Graphics)
            {
                using (new Font("Arial", 16))
                {
                    float x = new float();
                    float y = new float();
                    x = e.MarginBounds.Left;
                    y = e.MarginBounds.Top;

                    Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(350, 400);
                    grpReceipt.DrawToBitmap(bmp, new Rectangle(0, 0, 350, 400));
                    e.Graphics.DrawImage(bmp, x, y);

                }
            }
        }
```

FormImage:

[image: Form which has a groupbox only this to be printed]

When i try to run the above code it doesn't throw me any error but the first print works fine and all other are empty.

Where i'm wrong?

Comment: What does `Convert.ToInt32(lblTotalBox.Text` returns before the iteration ?

Comment: That will be as constant. Can be any number from 5-10.

Comment: What is printDocument1.Print()?

Comment: can you wrap the statement in a try catch and breakpoint on a possible exception?  Maybe trace the call at .Print?  My thinking is that .Print is throwing an exception that isn't occurring isn't making it to main(), so the app doesn't crash . .  .(and this is wild conjecture mind you!)

Comment: You don't need the `using(Graphics g = e.Graphics) { }` because you not creating a new graphics object, but assigning a reference to an existing one. Also you do not use `g` in your code.

Comment: Where do use set `e.HasMorePages = true;` ?

Comment: And use create a new font but you never assign it to a variable.

Comment: You are are printing a (350, 400) bitmap on a (100,65) paper size.

Answer (score 1):

Here is where you are wrong. You call the `printDocument1.Print()` inside a loop.

Try this:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        PrintDocument pd=new PrintDocument();
        int index=0, count=0;
        pd.BeginPrint+=(s, ev) =>
        {
            // find page count from form label
            count=int.Parse(label1.Text);
        };
        pd.PrintPage+=(s, ev) =>
        {
            // for each page
            index++;
            // get form size
            var size=this.Size;
            // create bitmap of same size
            var bmp=new Bitmap(size.Width, size.Height);
            // draw form into bitmap
            this.DrawToBitmap(bmp, new Rectangle(Point.Empty, size));
            // draw bitmap into graphics, resize to fit paper margins
            ev.Graphics.DrawImage(bmp, new Rectangle(ev.MarginBounds.Location, ev.MarginBounds.Size));
            // create a font and draw on graphics the page number
            using(var font = new Font(FontFamily.GenericSansSerif, 16f))
            {
                ev.Graphics.DrawString(index.ToString(), font, Brushes.Black, ev.MarginBounds.Location);
            }
            // check for final page
            ev.HasMorePages=index<count;
        };
        pd.EndPrint+=(s, ev) =>
        {
            // reset count and index
            index=0;
            count=0;
        };
        PaperSize paper=new PaperSize("MyCustomSize", 100, 65);
        paper.RawKind=(int)PaperKind.Custom;
        // set paper size
        pd.DefaultPageSettings.PaperSize=paper;
        // set paper margins appropriately
        pd.DefaultPageSettings.Margins=new Margins(10, 10, 10, 10);

        // call up the print preview dialog to see results
        PrintPreviewDialog dlg=new PrintPreviewDialog();
        dlg.Document=pd;
        dlg.ShowDialog();
    }
}
```

with a simple form like this:

[image: Form]

the **only** button creates a 10 page document like this:

[image: Printout]

### Updated Code

Per the comments below, I changed the printing code to:

```
// get form size
var size=groupBox1.Size;
// create bitmap of same size
var bmp=new Bitmap(size.Width, size.Height);
// draw form into bitmap
groupBox1.DrawToBitmap(bmp, new Rectangle(Point.Empty, size));
```

which grabs only the groupbox for drawing.

[image: UpdatedScreen]

Comment: I'm getting the whole form in my print. i need only the groupbox.

Comment: Please include a picture of your form in the posting so we know what you are talking about. Anyway change the `var size=this.Size;` to change the size of the bitmap, and adjust the `this.DrawToBitmap()` command to fit UI elements you want.

Comment: Added the form image. Kindy update the code to get only the groupbox print.

Comment: Is the whole thing a groupbox, or are you interested in one of the other boxes. It is still not clear from the posting what is what.

Comment: All the controls are inside the groupbox and i'm trying to print the whole groupbox.

Comment: See updated code now. This is a small change, in terms of where the `.DrawToBitmap()` is called from.

Answer (score 0):

I doubt that all the other prints are not empty, they just overlap each other. You should do something like this:

```
int nextTop = -1;
int i = 1;
private void printDocument1_PrintPage(object sender, PrintPageEventArgs e) {        
    for(;i <= Convert.ToInt32(lblTotalBox.Text); i++){
      lblBoxNumber.Text = i.ToString();
      using (Graphics g = e.Graphics) {
          int y = nextTop == -1 ? e.MarginBounds.Top : nextTop;           
          Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(350, 400);
          grpReceipt.DrawToBitmap(bmp, new Rectangle(0, 0, 350, 400));
          g.DrawImage(bmp, e.MarginBounds.Left, y);         
          nextTop += bmp.Height + 10;
          if(nextTop > e.MarginBounds.Height - bmp.Height) {
             nextTop = -1
             e.HasMorePages = true;
             return;
          }
      }
    }
}
private void btnPrint_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    i = 1;
    PaperSize paperSize = new PaperSize("MyCustomSize", 100, 65);
    paperSize.RawKind = (int)PaperKind.Custom;
    printDocument1.DefaultPageSettings.PaperSize = paperSize;
    printDocument1.Print();
}
```